# Substring issue when combined with map or reduce. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, substring, reduce

According to spec, when a second argument is omitted, substring should return n characters from the end of the string.

If embedded in an array map or reduce, substring with a single argument seems to do nothing.

I have tried the following in both nodejs and in the browser console (firefox), however get "incorrect" output:

```js
let a = [["g9qleb3ycfzs2rgrqebjtqol",1],["amjjvjvz3d7hvl7eu9k9alfj",1]]

let b = a.reduce((p,[x, y]) => [ ...p, [ x.substring(1), y ] ],[])
let c = a.map(([x, y]) => [ x.substring(1), y ]);

// Expected: [["l",1],["j",1]]
// Received: [["g9qleb3ycfzs2rgrqebjtqol",1],["amjjvjvz3d7hvl7eu9k9alfj",1]]
console.log(b) 

// Expected: [["l",1],["j",1]]
// Received: [["g9qleb3ycfzs2rgrqebjtqol",1],["amjjvjvz3d7hvl7eu9k9alfj",1]]
console.log(c) // should return: [["l",1],["j",1]]
```

When I use two arguments for the substring method (e.g. to return first value of string), it works as expected:

```js
let a = [["g9qleb3ycfzs2rgrqebjtqol",1],["amjjvjvz3d7hvl7eu9k9alfj",1]]

let b = a.reduce((p,[x, y]) => [ ...p, [ x.substring(0,1), y ] ],[])
let c = a.map(([x, y]) => [ x.substring(0,1), y ]);

// Expected: [["g",1],["a",1]]
// Received: [["g",1],["a",1]]
console.log(b) 

// Expected: [["g",1],["a",1]]
// Received: [["g",1],["a",1]]
console.log(c) // should return: [["l",1],["j",1]]
```

Does anyone have any insight to this?

Comment: _"when a second argument is omitted, substring should return n characters from the end of the string"_ - What's `n` in your case? The input (ie: 1)? That's not how `substring()` works when the second argument is omitted. It'll return all characters up until the end of the string when the second arg is omitted (I suggest reading the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) rather than the spec as it tends to be easier to understand)

Comment: Also `b` and `c` in the first example gives `[["9qleb3ycfzs2rgrqebjtqol",1],["mjjvjvz3d7hvl7eu9k9alfj",1]]`, not the result you've highlighted in the code comments.

Comment: You're 100% correct - I'd miss-read the following line in the mozilla docs as FROM the end rather than TO the end:
- "If indexEnd is omitted, substring() extracts characters to the end of the string."

Thanks for your help!